# Match one regex group member 1 or n times

Tags: python, regex

I have a line like this, with a \t at the beginning:

```
    {ABC-1234-22 ABC-2345-4444}
```

With my [first regex](https://regex101.com/r/znTUCv/1)

```
\t\{(ABC-\d{4}-\d+)\s?\}
```

I find only one match. In [another try](https://regex101.com/r/mHQu2S/1) I find one or two but not more:

```
\t\{(ABC-\d{4}-\d+)\s?(ABC-\d{4}-\d+)*\}
```

But I want to get 1 or n matches.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You may use `\t\{ABC-\d{4}-\d+(?:\s+ABC-\d{4}-\d+)*\}`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mHQu2S/3). There is no need capturing the groups since you can't access them later with Python `re`. If you need them, grab the match with the regex above and run `re.findall(r'ABC-\d{4}-\d+', match)` on the match(es).

Comment: As seen in the comment of @WiktorStribiżew, you are missing the whitespace which should be repeated also multiple times. Currently you are matching `CVE-1234-12 CVE1234-236CVE8697-4256CVE1245-12`. As you notice, no spaces.

Comment: But I need each ABC-xxxx-xx as a group match.

Comment: @JohnnyFromBF, what do you mean, you want to reference it again later on?

Comment: Then re-read my comment. Or are you using PyPi regex module?

Comment: You can get each match as a separate group by using `(?:\t\{|(?!^)\G)\s*(ABC-\d{4}-\d+)(?=[^{]*})` though it requires `regex` module instead of `re`: Check this working here: https://regex101.com/r/znTUCv/2

Comment: @anubhava With `regex`, OP would have access to all the captures and `r'\t\{(?:\s*(ABC-\d{4}-\d+))*\s*}'` [would work](https://rextester.com/UEBO43991) too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the hint, I tried it but match is None in Python 3. Tried this:

`rw = re.compile(r'\t\{ABC-\d{4}-\d+(?:\s+ABC-\d{4}-\d+)*\}')
match = rw.match("  {ABC-1111-22}")
print(re.findall(r'ABC-\d{4}-\d+', str(match)))`

Comment: @JohnnyFromBF Mind the right package, [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/). And that is not a hint, that is a solution. The first comment shows the basic solution for the basic `re` library.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well for me it doesn't work, but okay.

Comment: [It works well](https://rextester.com/MZGPAY93766). When it "doesn't work", you must always provide a demo link, otherwise, no one can help you fix the issue.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Okay, will do. Thanks!